# How to use Scrapy XPath with XML namespaces?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy, xml-namespaces

How do I extract `<content:encoded> ... </content:encoded>` content using scrapy XPath from an [RSS feed](https://reason.com/latest/feed/) (sample below)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0"
     xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
  <channel>
    <title>Latest &#8211; Reason.com</title>
    <item>
        <pubDate>Thu, 16 Jan 2020 21:40:23 +0000</pubDate>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p><span style="font-weight: 400">
          Jimmy Meders was scheduled to die by lethal injection today, 
          but the Georgia parole board has granted him clemency.</span></p>]]> 
        </content:encoded>
...
```

I tried `response.xpath('//content:encoded').get()`, but it's not working.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare and register an XML namespace prefix:

```
response.selector.register_namespace('content', 
                                     'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/')
response.xpath('//content:encoded').getall()
```

**Documentation:** [register_namespace()](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.register_namespace)